How to load pretrained model to transformers pipeline and specify multi-gpu?
I have a local server with multiple GPUs and I am trying to load a local model and specify which GPU to use since we want to split GPU between team members.
I can successfully specify 1 GPU using device_map='cuda:3' for smaller model, how to do this on multiple GPU like CUDA:[4,5,6] for larger model?
(I tried using device_map = 'auto', 'balanced', 'sequential', which will spread model automatically. But this is not what we want...)
import torch
from transformers import LlamaForCausalLM

model_dir = '/models/Llama-2-13b-chat-hf'

# 'auto' 'balanced' 'sequential' 'balanced_low_0'
# 'cuda:3',

model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_dir,
                                         device_map='cuda:[3,4,5]',#how to make things work here?
                                         torch_dtype=torch.float32 
                                        )


I guess the easiest way to achieve what you want is exporting CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES:
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1"
#or
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0,1"

import torch
from transformers import LlamaForCausalLM

model_dir = '/models/Llama-2-13b-chat-hf'
model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_dir,
                                         device_map='auto')

If you want to use the device_map you have to map each layer by yourself:
# distillroberta because it is smaller

from transformers import AutoModelForMaskedLM

model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("distilbert/distilroberta-base")
# parameter names
print([x[0] for x in model.named_parameters()])

Output:
['roberta.embeddings.word_embeddings.weight',
 'roberta.embeddings.position_embeddings.weight',
 'roberta.embeddings.token_type_embeddings.weight',
 'roberta.embeddings.LayerNorm.weight',
 'roberta.embeddings.LayerNorm.bias',
 'roberta.encoder.layer.0.attention.self.query.weight',
 'roberta.encoder.layer.0.attention.self.query.bias',
...
 'roberta.encoder.layer.5.output.LayerNorm.weight',
 'roberta.encoder.layer.5.output.LayerNorm.bias',
 'lm_head.bias',
 'lm_head.dense.weight',
 'lm_head.dense.bias',
 'lm_head.layer_norm.weight',
 'lm_head.layer_norm.bias']

You don't need to map each weight. It is enough when you map the layers:
# device map example for distillroberta:
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForMaskedLM

device_map= {'roberta.embeddings':'cpu', 'roberta.encoder':0, 'lm_head':'cpu'}

model = AutoModelForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("distilbert/distilroberta-base", device_map = device_map)

